# Why HTML updates but CSS don't follow on my Wordpress site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Before posting here, I tried pretty much everything I could based on the knowledge I have on Wordpress to fix this issue. I contacted technical support, I asked help from my hosting service, but nothing came out of it. So I came here to ask you for help, cause i'm losing my mind on this!

Right, so here's my problem. I had to make a website for work using Wordpress, which I did, using a plugin called [PostX](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-post/) to display beautiful news items and titles. I guess what it does is adding fancy CSS to some < div> and <h*> titles (but I have no idea how it actually works).
Now, the problem is, some random day, as I was modifying the home page to add some text and published it, all the CSS of the plugin's blocks broke.

- Here is what the page looked like (french version is not broke as it was not edited) : https://inseedev.nexen.net/DMCSI2022/fr/accueil/
- Here is what it looks after editing : https://inseedev.nexen.net/DMCSI2022/

You may think that what I modified on the page is responsible for the CSS to not be applied anymore on this specific page, but here's the thing: wherever I just press the button "Edit page" on my site, on any page, every elements of the Plugin break on this page. Even if i don't edit a damn thing, but just publish right away.
Even weirder : the CSS is alright in the embedded editor preview, but it still breaks when the page is published.
Weirder again : this does not happen on my site cloned to another hosting server (well to be honest it does, but... pretty rarely, and publishing again fix it!).

Also, If I create a brand new page or post or anything and add a block of this Plugin, it will be broken when published. It's like anything updated or created with the plugin will not be working anymore so i can't touch my site...

Things you may find useful:

- Both the plugin, wordpress and the themes have been updated multiples times in the last 3 months and are now up to date : didn't fix anything.
- I tried deleting the plugin and reinstalling it again. I tried desactivating other plugins too.
- I couldn't find anyone having the same issue in the support forums, which tends to make me thing that the plugin is quite functional usually.
- I found out that the html classes of plugin elements change everytime I edit&publish, for instance, the title "LATEST NEWS" go from "< div class="ultp-block-399cad">"  to "< div class="ultp-block-f9e072">" while the CSS properties stays at "#ultp-block-39cad { }"
  . So if i'm not mistaken, it means that the CSS is not updating. But why? What can cause a plugin to update HTML but not CSS all of a sudden ? Can there be a server cache for css files ? Do you have any other idea ?

I am lost!

Thank you for reading me,
Florian

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. You wrote literally a wall of text with abrely any useful informations that would help us to help you fixing the issues.

Comment: PS: Severs dont cache CSS. Servers don't render websites, that what the browser does by requesting the files and downloading them.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answering. I don't know what produce the bug so i cant not tell you more to help you reproduce it. I could tell you to create a wordpress website and download the plugin I linked and hope for the best? I really don't know what's causing it, plus it doesn't happen on my other hosting service. What information would help ?

Comment: The main issue with your question is the scope for SO. SO is not a forum or customer support. See SO as Wikipedia or library for developers that collect specific coding issues. WIth an issue that can not be reproduced here is not self-containing and as such has no value for the community. As such it also has no place here. If we need to create our own website and download a plugin to find a possible issue to reproduce it, then this would fail the concept and scope of SO. We would need to invest a major portion of time and resources for something that has no furtehr value to the community.

Comment: Well forums and customer supports are not helping me so i try what I can. Plus, If I found on SO a post about someone having this kind of issue it would have helped me so it would have a value to the community. And I'm sure i won't be the only one having this kind of problem. Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: This might be some client caching problem - have u tried using a different browser?

Comment: Yes, I tried... Chrome, Mozilla, Edge, same problem, on other machines too.

Comment: Removing the plugin and installing it again. Some ppl refer to corrupted files.